# Regular expression for { } object for

Tags: regex

I have a huge file with a lot of stuff that looks like:

```
    skaune.malmo = rsr.path("m 640.4,516.9 3.9,-2.8 23.8,1.2 13.6,-5.2 3,-3.9 17.4,-1.8 1.2,-3.4 9.7,-4.6 0.5,-1.5 -7.3,-10.3 12.5,-4.5 -2.3,-4.1 3.9,-6.1 -3.4,-11.3 -2.7,-4.6 -2.3,-1.1 -6.4,3.4 -7.2,-0.7 -1.2,-6.8 -5.6,1.1 0,-10.6 -6.8,-5.7 0,-1.1 -11.4,-4.1 -4.1,4.1 0,2.3 1.9,1.5 0,3 -1.9,1.1 -1.1,1.6 -7.2,3 -5.3,0.4 -2.7,1.1 -5.2,5.7 -3.4,3.4 -10.2,5.2 -2.7,3.4 -3,4.6 -1.1,4.5 0,6.8 0,5.7 0.7,5 5.6,12.4 3.4,9.8 3.4,3.9").attr({id: 'path4',parent: 'Skanska_kommuner',fill: '#5eacdd','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'}).transform("t-40.677966,-76.271186").data('id', 'path4');
    skaune.bjuv = rsr.path("m 643.8,137 -6.3,-2.8 -2.3,6.8 0,2.8 4.1,10.8 5,8 4.1,0 -0.7,7.3 -3.9,4 3.9,1.2 5.2,12.4 0,1.2 -1.1,2.7 -10.9,-1.1 -1.6,1.8 2.7,3.4 3,-1.2 1.1,5.7 -1.1,5.7 2.7,2.2 -2.7,-0.6 0,0.6 -0.7,5.7 3.4,1.2 1.1,-3 9.8,7.5 2.3,-3.4 3.8,2.3 7.5,-3 7.9,-4.5 -3.4,-11.8 10.2,5 1.6,-2.8 -6.8,-6.3 4.1,-11.3 -4.5,-5 5,-4.6 5.2,0.5 3.8,-8.4 1.8,-5.2 6.9,0 -2.3,-11.4 -3.4,0.7 -4.6,-3.4 -12.4,-14.7 -5.2,2.2 -14.8,-8.6 -3.8,0.7 -5.3,0 -1.5,0 1.5,3.9 -3.4,0 -5,6.8").attr({id: 'path6',parent: 'Skanska_kommuner',fill: '#5eacdd','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'}).transform("t-40.677966,-76.271186").data('id', 'path6');
    skaune.astarp = rsr.path("m 713,149.4 3.9,-5.6 -8,-5 8,-13.2 -8,-8.4 -5.6,-18.1 -10.7,2.3 0,-6.8 -7.5,-9.1 -7.2,3.8 -9.8,0 0,3 -6.8,16.3 -3.8,4.5 -13.7,2.3 0,-3.4 -5.6,0.7 0,3.9 -14.8,3.3 1.2,5.7 -1.2,1.8 -1.8,2.8 1.8,4 1.2,2.8 2.7,1.8 7.9,3.4 1.8,-8 6.8,2.8 5,-6.8 3.4,0 -1.5,-3.9 1.5,0 5.3,0 3.8,-0.7 14.8,8.6 5.2,-2.2 12.4,14.7 8.4,6.8 0,-4.1 10.9,0").attr({id: 'path8',parent: 'Skanska_kommuner',fill: '#5eacdd','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'}).transform("t-40.677966,-76.271186").data('id', 'path8');
    skaune.orkelljunga = rsr.path("m 753.8,1.6 10.7,-5.7 9.8,-9.1 0,-6.3 18.1,-16.4 15.9,-2.2 13.6,-15.5 19.3,-1.5 7.9,-6.4 12.5,14.8 4.5,-3.4 10.2,5.2 13.6,-3 6.8,-3.8 0.5,2.2 -7.3,1.6 -0.7,9.8 -20.4,10.6 -5,16.6 -4.5,1.6 6.1,25.6 -6.8,2.3 1.8,5.6 -4,2.3 -3.9,-9.1 -7.9,-1.1 -4.6,7.9 -4.5,0.5 0,9.1 -4.5,6.8 -25.7,-2.7 -27.6,32.8 -14.3,-2.2 -3.9,3.8 0,6.4 -6.8,6.1 -8.6,-3.9 1.8,-8.6 -7.9,0.7 -3.4,-7.9 -9.1,-5.7 -2.3,-7.9 11.4,-4.6 -10.9,-5.2 2.9,-3.8 1.2,0 6.8,-1.2 9,-9.1 10.2,-17.6 0,-8.4").attr({id: 'path10',parent: 'Skanska_kommuner',fill: '#5eacdd','stroke-width': '0','stroke-opacity': '1'}).transform("t-40.677966,-76.271186").data('id', 'path10');
```

and so on... It has a function called `.attr({/alot of different stuff i want to delete/})` and I want to replace that with a variable called `attr.(style)`. So everything inside `{ ... }` should be replaced with style. How do I do that? What is the regexp string for `{ and everything inside }`?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like simply replacing `.attr(` with `.attr.style(` might suffice. If not, please provide which environment you're working in and a clear desired result. I'm unsure whether you wanna completely discard the content inside the `.attr` brackets, or put it in `.style`. And with or without curly brackets?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said what *kind* of regex, but in most types I know you're looking for:

```
attr\({[^}]+}\)
```

...and replacing with `attr(style)` (or `attr.(style)`, if that `.` after `attr` wasn't a typo). Depending on regex flavor, you may have to add or remove some backslashes there (for instance, with vim's default magic settings, I believe it would be `attr({[^}]\+})`). Basically:

- Match `attr({` literally
- Match all characters within the `{}` using `[^}]+`
- Match `})` literally